# How to include .net framework 4.5.1 in VS 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-setup-proje

I want to create an installer for Windows application, and to include .NET Framework into that installation (I have selected * Download from the same site as my application). But in compilation of Setup project I get an error, saying that there is no framework installation exists. How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? It's useful for people with the same problem searching with the error message.

Comment: It is unwise to get into the business of providing your own .NET Framework install server.  Short from not having one as the error message says, it is fairly unlikely you'll keep up with the patches and security updates.  Select "vendor's web site" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the flowing [Microsoft post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/17/net-framework-4-5-1-rtm-gt-start-coding.aspx) you can find what you have to install:

• [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/download/details.aspx?id=40773)

• [Visual Studio 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads) ([SDKs and targeting packs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dn250998.aspx))

4.5.1 is required part of VS2013, without it you can't run VS2013. If you have installed VS2013, you have installed 4.5.1. To create msi installers you need to add a extension:

[visual-studio-installer-projects-extension](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads)